# Styling content-switching links as radio buttons

Tags: html, css, transition, fade

I'm trying to mix two behaviors. I can get them to work one at a time, but not both together.
What I want is, specifically, to be able to transition between content by clicking on one of three images, which will fade when not clicked and become less transparent when active. I'm having some problems making the opacity work, but I can probably figure that out on my own.

Here's what I've done for the first half. The CSS is repeated for each div, with slight variation: see [the jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLWmv/) for the sum.

```
<label class="timeline" for="adult">
<input id="adult" type="radio" name="timeline" value="large" />
<a href=#1><img src=http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/e/k/7/a/a/carton-open-box-md.png width=200px height=auto></a>
</label>

<div id="1">THIS IS ONE</div>
<div id="2">THIS IS TWO</div>
<div id="3">THIS IS THREE</div>
```

Here's the second half. The HTML for each div is repeated, with slight variation. See [the jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mchWV/) for the sum.

```
<label class="timeline" for="adult">
<input id="adult" type="radio" name="timeline" value="big" />
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/e/k/7/a/a/carton-open-box-md.png" width=200px height=auto>
```

```
.timeline > input[type=radio]{
display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + img{
cursor:pointer;
border:2px solid transparent;
opacity:20%;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + img{
border:2px solid #f00;
opacity:80%;
}
```

Additionally, and this is what makes this difficult: I want to do this in CSS and HTML. No jquery or Javascript if at all possible.

Comment: to set 80% opacity : `opacity: 0.8;`

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know of a (css) way to fade between the two, so it's not a jarring jump from .2 to .8?
new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mchWV/1/

Comment: [Use transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mchWV/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mchWV/3/).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.
New Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mchWV/4/

Comment: your new fiddle is working fine right. now any problem is still out there?

Answer (score 0):

I think reason you can't do both effects at the same time is because you're using `:target` which means when you click the image/link only target will 'fire' meaning that your radiobutton never actually gets checked. This is just my guess based on looking at/trying your code, I haven't experimented enough with `:target` myself to confirm this.

The easiest way you can solve this is by moving your divs så that they're inside of your label instead of outside, this way you can target the `DIVS` the way you target your images.

```css
.timeline{display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
.timeline > input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + img{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
    opacity:0.2;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + img{
    opacity:0.8;
}
input[type=radio] ~ div{display: none;}
input[type=radio]:checked ~ div{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<label class="timeline" for="child">
    <input id="child" type="radio" name="timeline" value="small" />
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/e/k/7/a/a/carton-open-box-md.png" width=200px height=auto />
    <div>THIS IS ONE</div>
  </label>
  
  <label class="timeline" for="teen">
    <input id="teen" type="radio" name="timeline" value="med"/>
      <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/e/k/7/a/a/carton-open-box-md.png" width=200px height=auto />
      <div>THIS IS TWO</div>
  </label>
  
  <label class="timeline" for="adult">
    <input id="adult" type="radio" name="timeline" value="big" />
      <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/e/k/7/a/a/carton-open-box-md.png" width=200px height=auto />
      <div>THIS IS THREE</div>
  </label>
```